# How to call an @AfterMethod testing method in one class after executing a test case in another class?

Tags: java, testng

abc.java

```
public abc {
    public test1(){}
    public test2(){}
    public test3(){}
}
```

def.java

```
public def {
   @AfterMethod
   public calc{}
}
```

How do I call the method calc in def.class after executing a testcase in abc.class??

Comment: I don't want to call the calc method explicitly after each testcase

Comment: Isn't `@AfterMethod` testng, not junit?

Comment: thanks skaffman for the update

Comment: just include jUnit testing framework and then you can add check as and when you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have `@AfterMethod` in Test Class scope so you can do:

`public class abc extends def {}`

or just move `calc()` to `abc` class.